# Get parent objects without active childs

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

I've two models, `Doctor` and `DoctorClinic` where a `doctor` `has_many` `clinics`.

**`doctor.rb:`**

```
has_many :clinics, class_name: 'DoctorClinic', dependent: :destroy
```

**`doctor_clinic.rb`**

```
belongs_to :doctor
```

`DoctorClinic` have `doctor_id` and a boolean `active` field.

**What I want:**

I want to get all `doctors` which does not have any active (`active` field is `true`) clinics. If a doctor have two clinics, out of which one is active and other is inactive then doctor should not be selected.

Doctor record will be selected if,

- there's no clinics at all
- if there's any clinic but all are inactive, i.e. all have `active` `false`.

Doctor will not be selected if,

- there's any active clinics.

**What I've tried so far:**

**Try 1:**

```
scope :incomplete_doctors, -> { includes(:clinics)
                                .where("( doctor_clinics.id IS NULL ) OR
                                        ( doctor_clinics.id IS NOT NULL AND
                                            doctor_clinics.active=?)", false )
                              }
```

**Try 2:**

```
scope :incomplete_doctors, -> { where("id NOT IN (?)", self.includes(:clinics)
                            .where("( doctor_clinics.doctor_id IS NULL ) OR
                                      ( doctor_clinics.doctor_id IS NOT NULL AND
                                          doctor_clinics.active=?)", false )
                            .select(:id))
                            }
```

**Try 3:**

```
SELECT "doctors".* FROM "doctors"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "doctor_clinics" ON "doctor_clinics"."doctor_id" = "doctors"."id"
  WHERE ( ( doctor_clinics.id IS NULL ) OR
          ( doctor_clinics.id IS NOT NULL AND
              doctor_clinics.active='f'))
  GROUP BY doctors.id
    HAVING 'true' <> ANY(array_agg(DISTINCT doctor_clinics.active::TEXT));
```

**Success:**

I'm able to achieve desired output using following method, but I want to achieve this using a SQL query.

```
def active_clinics
  clinics.active_clinics # active_clinics is a scope in Clinic model while give all active clinics
end

def self.incomplete_doctors
  (Doctor.all.map { |d| d unless d.active_clinics.present? }).compact
end
```

Comment: does this work? `left_outer_joins(:doctor_clinics).where( 'doctor_clinics.id = ? OR doctor_clinics.active = ?', nil, false )` in scope as `Doctor.unassociated`

Comment: Nope. It fails when there are two `clinics`, one is active and other is inactive.  In this case, doctor should not be selected. I've just added more information  in the question.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon, Also, `left_outer_joins` doesn't work (atleast in Rails 3) and `includes` is equivalent to `left_outer_join`. So, I updated that scope to `{includes(:clinics).where( 'doctor_clinics.id = ? OR doctor_clinics.active = ?', nil, false ) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick in pure SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM doctors
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM doctor_clinics
  WHERE 
    doctor_clinics.doctor_id = doctors.id 
    AND doctor_clinics.active = true 
)
```

You should be able to use it with `find_by_sql`:

```
Doctor.find_by_sql(SQL)
```

Have no Rails 3 project to actually test it;-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.